# Using the Canvas element with the HTML 4 doctype works fine. How come?

Tags: html, doctype, html4

Using the [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) element with the [HTML 4 `<!DOCTYPE>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) works fine in all browsers, even though `<canvas>` is an HTML5 feature. How come?

Isn't the page supposed to break if we're using the older `<!DOCTYPE>`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: No, not at all. What makes you think it should break? Why would browser makers go to the trouble of making it break?

Comment: To help web developers test their websites while simulating older browsers.

Comment: Oh OK. There are, for instance, 33 versions of versions of Google Chrome, all of which have been created in era of HTML4/HTML5. Which of those versions should the latest version emulate? No, browsers don't do that, except IE, and even it doesn't select the emulated version by DOCTYPE. Browsers only use quirks and standards modes to support old web pages, and then seek to keep the number of differences to a minimum. They do so for the benefit of *users* not web devs. Old web pages won't break because canvas is supported in them, since they won't be using canvas anyway.